# How edit CSS file in web2py

Tags: css, web2py, web2py-modules

How could I edit CSS files in web2py ?

I wanna override the web2py_table, someone could help me ?

I inspected in google chrome, but the file who is pointing don't make the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The web2py CSS rules are set in the application's /static/css/web2py.css file ([here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/ad43249f6148402890077a0a649e46b42fa6a8ab/applications/welcome/static/css/web2py.css#L262) is the relevant line for the version in the "welcome" app).

If making the change there doesn't work, then the problem must be with some other aspect of the CSS, so we'll need more information.